# Non identity character of an Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, characters

How does one show that for any non-trivial abelian group, there exists some non-trivial character?

After looking up for a while, the best solution I could find was Pontrayagin duality, which seems like too heavy a machinery for this problem.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681017/is-there-a-non-trivial-character-on-any-locally-compact-abelian-group). Is it true that you allow arbitrary abelian groups?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have looked at that, I was hoping for an easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the fact that $GL_1(\mathbb{C})$ is a divisible and hence injective abelian group.  So given any abelian group $A$, a subgroup $B\subseteq A$, and a homomorphism $f:B\to GL_1(\mathbb{C})$, $f$ can be extended to a homomorphism $A\to GL_1(\mathbb{C})$.  Now if $A$ is any nontrivial abelian group, let $B$ be a nontrivial cyclic subgroup of $A$.  It is easy to explicitly construct a nontrivial homomorphism $B\to GL_1(\mathbb{C})$, which then extends to $A$.

(I doubt you will find any simpler proof than this for arbitrary abelian groups--I'm pretty sure this is impossible to prove without using the axiom of choice, for instance.)

Comment: Baer's criterion needs Zorn's lemma, right?

Comment: Right, that's where the axiom of choice is used in this argument.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. By the way, a natural question that cropped up in my mind is, does Pontryagin duality require the axiom of choice? I don't know it's proof, so I can't comment myself.

Comment: @MathManiac: Yes, Pontryagin duality uses the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary abelian groups something non-trivial has to be used, it seems. For *finite* abelian groups, though, we have a very elementary Lemma:

*Lemma:* Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $a,b$ distinct elements in $G$. Then there exists a character $\chi$ of $G$ such that $\chi(a)\neq \chi(b)$.

For a proof see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=5H6BCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=give+an+example+of+a+non-trivial+character+for+an+abelian+group&source=bl&ots=hmVzGjJ2YX&sig=KDOOhrOByN12phAAhmewJr5ZGSg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_xvSQmu3RAhWqbZoKHVd5COEQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=give%20an%20example%20of%20a%20non-trivial%20character%20for%20an%20abelian%20group&f=false), Lemma $1.3.33$. So for $n=|G|\ge 2$ we see that there exists a non-trivial character of $G$.

Comment: I think the OP is mainly concerned with the less easy case of non finitely generated groups.

Comment: I see. Then we need more. Actually, Noam Elkies says we do need Pontryagin duality, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681017/is-there-a-non-trivial-character-on-any-locally-compact-abelian-group).